# Can i return a custom contentView in UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can i return a custom contentView in UICollectionViewCell?

I have attempted multi ways, but to no avail. I kept getting complain that `because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

```
- (UIView *)contentView {
return [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: add your custom view to cell as sub view & add constraints

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) as Zeeshan suggested you can add your custom `UIView` as a subview of the contentView of your `UICollectionViewCell` and set the proper constraints to it;

```
    [contentView addSubview:myContentView];
    [myContentView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop];
    [myContentView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom];
    [myContentView autoPinWidthToSuperview];
```

2) make your cell as a custom view, you just need it to extend a `UICollectionViewCell`, so then you can use it when you need it.

Also if this is not what you want please post more of your code, so everyone can have a better understanding.